# View all oracle db connections for a specific date and time

Tags: database, oracle, connection-pooling

I am just trying to view all connections on a oracle db at a given date and time. I know about V$SESSION view but that seems to only give the current connections. The best way to describe what I am looking for is a connection transaction table/view. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check the ASH option for historic sessions.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber - Correction:  "Check the ASH option for historic session _if you are licensed for its use_."

Comment: @edStevens you forgot *check if you are licenced for the Oracle database*, this is a *precondiion* to use ASH.

Comment: Are you looking for a list of connections, or what the connections did in terms of database transactions and system load? If you want a login history, you need to enable auditing. ASH (if you are licensed for it) would help you understand what those sessions did.

Comment: https://connor-mcdonald.com/2019/12/16/listener-log-data-mining-with-sql/